# updating chartjs pie chart by using .keypress() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to create a dynamic chartjs pie diagram. So far I have only been able to successfully adding an "update" function by using the jQuery .click function. However, I would like to also be able to update the chart by using the jQuery .keypress() function. I have therefore tried inserting this function into the  that creates the pie chart. This does for some reason, however, not seem to work.

I have tried changing the order of the functions, however, nothing seems to do the trick. I know the code is correct since it works if I copy and paste it into the console. So my suspicion is that it has something to do with firing the function after the page load, which I have tried doing by wrapping the .keypress() function into a window.ready() function, however, this did not do the trick either.

This is the code i use to insert the pie chart:

```
$(document).ready(function(chartData) {
    var childText = $('.noDisplay tbody').text();
    //Number of positives                          
    var positiveCount = (childText.match(/Positiv/g) || []).length;
    //Number of negatives
    var negativeCount = (childText.match(/Negativ/g) || []).length;
    //Find total number of tests
    var totalTests = positiveCount + negativeCount;
    //Calculate into %
    var positiveProcent = positiveCount / totalTests * 100;
    var negativeProcent = negativeCount / totalTests * 100;
    //With 2 decimals
    var positiveProcent2 = positiveProcent.toFixed(2);
    var negativeProcent2 = negativeProcent.toFixed(2);
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Positive tests i %", "Negative tests i %", ],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Positiv vs negativ',
                data: [positiveProcent2, negativeProcent2],
                backgroundColor: ['rgba(39, 174, 96, 0.5)', 'rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.5)', ],
                borderColor: ['rgba(39, 174, 96, 1)', 'rgba(231, 76, 60, 1)', ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {}
    });

    function updateChart() {
        var childText = $('.col-sm-12 #dataTable_wrapper').text();
        //Number of positives                          
        var positiveCount = (childText.match(/Positiv/g) || []).length;
        //Number of negatives
        var negativeCount = (childText.match(/Negativ/g) || []).length;
        //Find total number of tests
        var totalTests = positiveCount + negativeCount;
        //Calculate into %
        var positiveProcent = positiveCount / totalTests * 100;
        var negativeProcent = negativeCount / totalTests * 100;
        //With 2 decimals
        var positiveProcent2 = positiveProcent.toFixed(2);
        var negativeProcent2 = negativeProcent.toFixed(2);
        myChart.data.datasets[0].data = [positiveProcent2, negativeProcent2];
        myChart.update();
    }
    $('.kkTable #dataTable_filter > label').keypress(function() {
        console.log('1');
        updateChart();
    });
    $('button').click(function() {
        updateChart();
    });
});
```

How can i make the keypress() function work?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The label element will not emit a `keypress` event as far as I know. Are you sure you don't mean `.kkTable #dataTable_filter > label input` ?

Comment: Yeah i did. Just tried changing it to that, still doesn't work however :/

Comment: Does it log the 1? Because if not, there must be some other problem. Can you also append your HTML to the question?

Comment: No it does not, which also confuses me. I would do that, but the thing is I pull the data from a table that gets generated through PHP and then some sorting + search functions gets applied to the table using https://datatables.net. So I can't quite post the HTML without it being ridiculously long.

Comment: When you set the listener (the `keypress` part), is the HTML already there? Or are you generating the HTML at a later moment? Because that would explain why it doesn't work. Try changing your function to the following: `$(document).on('keypress', '.kkTable #dataTable_filter > label input', function() {`

Comment: The HTML is already there. However, your suggestion worked. But I dont understand why? I thought `$(document).on('keypress', '.kkTable #dataTable_filter > label input', function() {'` is the same as `$('.kkTable #dataTable_filter > label').keypress(function() {` ?

Do you have an idea about why that is?

Comment: The difference is that all events bubble up (propagate) the DOM tree and eventually end up on the `document`. The listener I provided listens to keypress events on the document and afterwards checks wether or not the event came from something that is according to the filter. So even with HTML that changes after the listener is set it would still work, the one you had only works with elements that both checks with the filter and are present at the moment it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by switching the listener from a very specific set of elements to the document with the previous selector as selector of the `on` method. Complete discussion enclosed:

> The label element will not emit a keypress event as far as I know. Are you sure you don't mean `.kkTable #dataTable_filter > label input` ? – **Douwe de Haan**
>
> Yeah i did. Just tried changing it to that, still doesn't work however :/ – **LENide300_KK**
>
> Does it log the 1? Because if not, there must be some other problem. Can you also append your HTML to the question? – **Douwe de Haan**
>
> No it does not, which also confuses me. I would do that, but the thing is I pull the data from a table that gets generated through PHP and then some sorting + search functions gets applied to the table using datatables.net. So I can't quite post the HTML without it being ridiculously long. – **LENide300_KK**
>
> When you set the listener (the keypress part), is the HTML already there? Or are you generating the HTML at a later moment? Because that would explain why it doesn't work. Try changing your function to the following: `$(document).on('keypress', '.kkTable #dataTable_filter > label input', function() {` – **Douwe de Haan**
>
> The HTML is already there. However, your suggestion worked. But I dont understand why? I thought `$(document).on('keypress', '.kkTable #dataTable_filter > label input', function() {`' is the same as `$('.kkTable #dataTable_filter > label').keypress(function() {` ? Do you have an idea about why that is? – **LENide300_KK**
>
> The difference is that all events bubble up (propagate) the DOM tree and eventually end up on the document. The listener I provided listens to keypress events on the document and afterwards checks wether or not the event came from something that is according to the filter. So even with HTML that changes after the listener is set it would still work, the one you had only works with elements that both checks with the filter and are present at the moment it is called. – **Douwe de Haan**